# Rviz .vcg vs .rviz (fuerte vs groovy)

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just to groovy and realized that my rviz config file, xx.vcg, no longer loads in rviz. Instead, if i save a configuration, it is saved as xx.rviz.

Is there any way to create a config file that will load in both fuerte's and groovy's rviz? I ask because I am creating a stack to run on either and would like to have as few differences as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53689/rviz-.vcg-vs-.rviz-(fuerte-vs-groovy)/) by [alexalspach](https://answers.ros.org/users/4012/alexalspach/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, the RViz config mechanism in Groovy is not backwards compatible.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could probably write a little utility function that converts files in the new YAML format (.rviz) to the old INI format (.vcg). Although you'd have to watch out for settings that may not have direct translations.

---

Originally posted by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) with karma: 452 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1